# PyCharm. Unexpected argument(s) Possible callees

Tags: python, pycharm, arguments

I write in PyCharm and get a bug (in line "func(dict_data)"): Unexpected argument(s) Possible callees: A.foo(dict_data: dict) A.bar(dict_data: dict).

Is it a PyCharm bug or am I doing something wrong?

PyCharm 2020.3

```py
    class A:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.functions = {
                "foo": self.foo,
                "bar": self.bar
            }
    
        def typing(self, dict_data: dict):
            for key, value in dict_data.items():
                if key in self.functions:
                    func = self.functions[value["type"]]
                    func(dict_data)
    
        def foo(self, dict_data: dict):
            print(dict_data)
    
        def bar(self, dict_data: dict):
            print(dict_data)
    
    
    class B:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = {
                "foo": {"type": "foo"},
                "bar": {"type": "bar"}
            }
    
        def get(self) -> dict:
            return self.data
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        b = B()
        data = b.get()
        a = A()
        a.typing(data)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not reconstructable on my 2019.1 pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func is actually a variable in your code, but you are calling it as a function which does not exist there, so PyCharm is guessing what function you might want to use instead which can accommodate dict_data as it's argument.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcUKO.png)

This 'def function_name(arguments : datatype)' in the pic is how function is identified but your ss has the keyword 'Union' and therefore func's datatype is Union.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to add a type hint to `func` like

```
func: Callable[[dict], None] = self.functions[value["type"]]
```

(Don't forget to add `from typing import Callable`)

This will get rid of the IDE warning by giving it additional information to correctly determine the types. Basically, it will no longer see `func` as a `Union` type but directly know that it's a `Callable` a known method signature.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the warning away by adding lambdas:

```
self.functions = {
                "foo": lambda x: self.foo,
                "bar": lambda x: self.bar
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the warning away by adding lambdas:

```
self.functions = {
                "foo": lambda x: self.foo(x),
                "bar": lambda x: self.bar(x)
            }
```